# Drupal 8 webform: How can multiple users add score to the same submission (eg: exam)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform, drupal-form-submission

Ho can two or more users add score to a single webform submission ?. Any exist solution available ?. 
I have a webform called exam contain (Name, Email and some questions, Score(1->10)). The problem here when the **user 1** add score (8), the **user 2** see the same value (8), so when he update the score field (8) to (10). The value (8) will be deleted. 
I want that the field be availble for each users ( instance). By this way, the **user 1** can add (8), the **user 2** can add (10) without loosing the two values. **Admin** can see the submission with the two scores value.  **Admin** can associate many users to evaluate submission and add score.(This is the point)

Comment: Is this something that will only ever receive two scores? Or is this more like a rating system?

Comment: I dont think , The admin can add 12 or more users to score the submission, so 12 scores (input) not the perfect solution, I just want to turn it dynamically. I mean , Just One (score) and each user have an instance of this score, what ever the number of users selected.@IsaiahNixon